# Strip suffix from all variable names in SPSS

Tags: python, spss

I have a dataset in which every variable name has the suffix "_1" (this was done to indicate the first interview timepoint). I want to remove this suffix from all variables, but there are hundreds of them, so I am looking for a way to do it without using the RENAME statement hundreds of times.

The closest to relevant info I found was from the link below, "A few SPSS loops for renaming variables dynamically." However, these examples show how to add a suffix or change a prefix, but not remove a suffix.

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/code/renaming_variables_dynamically.htm

I have the Python essentials package installed with SPSS, though I am not familiar with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no knowledge about SPSS. A quick search located an example of "Renaming variables using Python" with python (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/renaming_vars_Python.htm)

It would fit in your case by just a little change:

```
begin program.
import spss, spssaux
spssaux.OpenDataFile('d:\data\elemapi2.sav')
vdict=spssaux.VariableDict()
mylist=vdict.range(start="grad_sch", end="enroll")
nvars = len(mylist)

for i in range(nvars):
    myvar = mylist[i]
    mynewvar = myvar.strip("_1")
    spss.Submit(r"""
        rename variables ( %s = %s) .
                        """ %(myvar, mynewvar))
end program.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly tighter version of Jignesh's Python program.  It's functionally the same.

```
begin program.  
import spss, spssaux  
filteredvarlist=[v.VariableName for v in spssaux.VariableDict(pattern="^.*_1$")]  
spss.Submit( "rename variables (%s=%s)." %  
    ("\n".join(filteredvarlist), "\n".join([v[:-2] for v in filteredvarlist]))  
)  
end program.
```

Comment: Ahh yes, of course, the pattern filter on VariableDict! Jon, how about the speed performance of RENAME VARIABLES as multiple vs. single?

Comment: RENAME just manipulates the dictionary.  You would never be able to tell the difference in time between one and many  renames whether in a single submit or many, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution given on the [UCLA website](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/renaming_vars_Python.htm) works for that particular example/dataset, how the python program is coded it may not work as intended in all circumstances.

For example `"V01_1".strip("_1")` would result incorrectly in `"V0"` and something like `"V_1_1".strip("_1")` would result in simply `"V"`, again incorrectly and not as desired, if wanting to strip just the suffix.

And to be super critical, it also generates redundant `RENAME VARIABLES` commands even if the variable didn't have a `"_1"` suffix (although I know in your particular example you say *all* variables shall).

Also, it generates separate individual `RENAME VARIABLE` commands for each variable, not sure if this has a speed performance disadvantage than if generating a single `RENAME VARIABLES` command? Nonetheless, perhaps I demonstrate a different way of coding if you so required to code it in such a way:

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID V01_1 V02_1 V03_1 W_1_1 W_2_1 W_3_1.
BEGIN DATA
0 11 12 13 21 22 23
END DATA.

begin program.
spss.Submit(r"set mprint on.")
import spss, spssaux
allvarlist=[str(v) for v in spssaux.VariableDict()]
filteredvarlist=[v for v in allvarlist if v.endswith("_1")]
spss.Submit( "rename variables (\n" \
     + "\n".join(filteredvarlist) \
     + "\n=\n" \
     + "\n".join([v[:-2] for v in filteredvarlist]) \
     + ").")
spss.Submit(r"set mprint off.")
end program.
```