# Strip prefix from all variable names in SPSS

Tags: python, variables, macros, rename, spss

I have a similar question as asked here ([Strip suffix from all variable names in SPSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798827/strip-suffix-from-all-variable-names-in-spss)) and the answers there already helped a lot but there is still one question remaining.

I have a dataset in which every variable name has the prefix "v23_1_". I want to remove this prefix from all variables, but there are hundreds of them, so I am looking for a way to do it without using the RENAME statement hundreds of times.

I used this code:

```
begin program.
vdict=spssaux.VariableDict()
mylist=vdict.range(start="v23_1_dg_mnpdocid", end="v23_1_phq9t0_asku3t0")
nvars = len(mylist)

for i in range(nvars):
    myvar = mylist[i]
    mynewvar = myvar.strip("v23_1_")
    spss.Submit(r"""
        rename variables ( %s = %s) .
                        """ %(myvar, mynewvar))
end program.
```

Here is a list of the first few variables:

```
v23_1_dg_mnppusid
v23_1_dg_sigstatus
v23_1_dg_mnpvsno
v23_1_dg_mnpvslbl
v23_1_dg_mnpcvpid
v23_1_dg_mnpvisid
v23_1_dg_mnpvisno
v23_1_dg_mnpvispdt
v23_1_dg_mnpvisfdt
v23_1_dg_mnpfs0
v23_1_dg_mnpfs1
v23_1_dg_mnpfs2
v23_1_dg_mnpfs3
v23_1_dg_mnpfcs0
v23_1_dg_mnpfcs1
v23_1_dg_mnpfcs2
```

It worked ok for the first variables but then stopped with the message "renaming has created two variables named dg_mnpfs". But the next variable would after stripping has the name "dg_mnpfs2". What has happened is that the 1 at the end in "v23_1_dg_mnpfs1" gets deleted too. And then it propbably intends to also delete the 2 at the end in "v23_1_dg_mnpfs2", which will then lead to the same variable. I don't understand why this is happening and how I can avoid it.

Thanks a lot for your support!
Kind regards,
Beate

Comment: Hi Beate, welcome to stack overflow. if it's not confidential data, can you post the list of variables you are trying to get renamed ? Your code looks fine, in general, and I think the bug is related to your specific variable names

Comment: Thank you Horace! I added a list in the question and explained the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you syntax looks right now, it will run on a variable-by-variable basis. You are submitting/running the `RENAME VARIABLES` command as many times as the number of variables in your list.
On one hand, this is in-efficient, as it takes longer to run than what I am suggesting below.
On the other (and more important) hand, doing it variable by variable, does not guard against duplicate variables. I am guessing that you already have in your datafile a variable named `dg_mnpfs`, and you are attempting to create a new one by renaming `v23_1_dg_mnpfs`. Just check your datafile, after your python code breaks.

A more efficient way of writing you code would be to create lists with the old names, and new names, and submit the syntax with only one command.

```
begin program.
import spss,spssaux
vdict=spssaux.VariableDict()
mylist=vdict.range(start="v23_1_dg_mnpdocid", end="v23_1_phq9t0_asku3t0")
nvars = len(mylist)

my_new_list=[]
for i in range(nvars):
    myvar = mylist[i]
    mynewvar = myvar.strip("v23_1_")
    my_new_list.append(mynewvar)

my_syntax="ren var (" + " ".join(mylist) + "=" + " ".join(my_new_list) +")."
spss.Submit(my_syntax)
end program.
```

And one more thing: the `strip` function removes the text from both ends of the variables. If you only want to remove the prefix, consider using `lstrip`. Details can be found [here, in the official documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip)

Comment: Thanks a million Horace!! It worked with "lstrip" :). Yet, I still don't really understand why it strips the 1 and the 2 at the end of the variable names as the part it is asked to strip is defined as "v23_1_".  My gut feeling said that it should really search for the whole phrase "v23_1_" and just strip this.

Comment: so `v23_1_dg_mnpfs1` gets renamed into `v23_1_dg_mnpfs` even with my code ? Are you sure it is the same variable ? you are seeing it in the same row in Variable View ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of the process using SPSS macro. Using `SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES` lets you get the whole list of all relevant variables, whatever order they are in, without naming them in the command:

```
*this is just to create a sample data to play with.
data list list/v23_1_var1 to v23_1_var6.
begin data
end data.
```

The following creates a list of the relevant variables:

```
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!list" /PROPERTIES  PATTERN = "v23_1_*".
* the following macro creates one rename command for all the list. 
define !doRename ()
rename variables (!eval(!list)=!do !i !in(!eval(!list)) !substr(!i, 7) !doend).
!enddefine.
!doRename .
```

Comment: Thank you eli-k. Have to try this too.

Comment: please let us know how the answers worked out for you, and select one if it solved your problem.